# SearchView and the NavigationUI - Showing previous results

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation, searchview

I have the following situation: 
I am listing a bunch of items using a RecyclerView. To integrate a search functionality in the app, I used the `NavigationUI` library and provided a `SearchView`. Using the `NavigationUI` library, I also added an Up button for navigating between fragments.
The code snippets for these parts are:

```
// MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        return navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

The fragment observes its viewmodel and also contains the search functionality:

```
class WordListFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var wordAdapter: WordAdapter
    private lateinit var searchView: SearchView

    private val viewModel: WordViewModel by lazy {
        val activity = requireNotNull(this.activity){
            "You can only access the categoryListViewModel after onActivityCreated()"
        }
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, WordViewModel.Factory(activity.application))
            .get(WordViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.wordList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<PagedList<Word>> {
            it?.apply {
                wordAdapter.submitList(it)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // use data binding
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentWordListBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_word_list, container, false)

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(viewLifecycleOwner)

        // initialize the adapter
        wordAdapter = WordAdapter(....)

        // setup the recyclerview
        binding.root.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.word_list_recycler_view).apply{
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 3)
            adapter = wordAdapter
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        // extract the initial query
        val query = savedInstanceState?.getString(LAST_SEARCH_QUERY) ?: DEFAULT_QUERY

        // start the initial search - when empty string is provided it gives me 
        // all Words from the 1st page in the backend
        viewModel.searchWords(query)
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putString(LAST_SEARCH_QUERY, viewModel.lastQueryValue())
    }

    // here I do all the setup for the searchview, adding a listener to it and so on
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.apply{
            queryHint = "Search"
            isIconified = false
            setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {

                    // start the search
                    viewModel.searchWords(query)
                    return false
                }

                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                    // nothing to do
                    return false
                }
            })
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val LAST_SEARCH_QUERY: String = ""
        private const val DEFAULT_QUERY = ""
    }
}
```

Nothing special here. Whenever the searchview submits a string, it will be passed to `searchWords(query)` which activates/invokes all the Retrofit network stuff which is then passed back to the adapter of the recyclerview which then populates the recyclerview (that happens in the onActivityCreated(), for the sake of brevity I left the viewmodel out)

My problem is that I always stuck with the last query. Let's say, the user types the word "My" into the SearchView, then the app gives the user all items containing the word "My". But I can not go back to the previous search. It shows only the result of the current search. How can I navigate back so that the results of the previous search are listed again. What I want is that the user should be able to navigate to the previous search when the Up button is pressed. Here a little demo of mine:

[image]

As you can see, first we have initial items showing up when the app starts. Then the user types "My", SearchView does its job and all items containing "My" are presented(for better differentiation of the results, one can see that the list of the search is a little bit shorter than in the initial case). But when the user presses the Up button, navigating to the previous/initial starting point is not possible at this stage. Why ?

I was taking the Youtube app as inspiration. As you probably know, in the Youtube app, whenever the user makes a search for a video, it could also go back to the previous search by clicking on the Up button (on the left of the SearchView) or the back button.
What is the usual way of doing that ? You have initial items listed on the Home fragment, and then based on the Search text given by the user, you show the user a list of different items but the user is also able to navigate back to the initial items. How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

What i see is that you need to reset the data in the RecyclerView once the up navigation happens.

Something like this

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        val navigateAction = navController.navigateUp()

        if(navigateAction){
         // Clear stuff in the search view
         // Update recyclerview data 
        }
        return navigateAction
    }
```